# If value matches another value in array display items JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of objects, in each object I have a date and time.

`onClick` of a `td` element (its a calendar) I check the time on the calendar, then check if it matches any times in my list of objects.

```
onSelect: function(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
        for (var prop in dateArray) {
            if (date === dateArray[prop].date) {
                console.log(dateArray[prop].time);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I loop through my array, which is an array of objects. To be able to get anything out I need to do a for in loop, and in there I do a condional statement to say if the dates match. The console.log out the corect time.

However, the time gets console logged out 10 times since it's in a loop. But the only way I could get inside my object array was to loop through them.

How should I actually be doing this.

---

***EDIT***

dateArray structure: list of objects like `[ object, object, object, object ]` and once I loop through them, within each object it looks like :

```
Object {title: "The Title", date: "01/01/2017", time: "07:30pm", available: true,}
```

Comment: use indexOf function in javascript. If value is there it will return index or it will return -1.

Comment: does `for (var prop in dateArray)` actually give you an index number to use in `dateArray[prop]`? shouldn't you be using `i`?

Comment: @Coderchu I don't know if I should be looping twice. Date is coming from jQuery Date picker. It's basically a list of all the dates in the current month.

Comment: You should show us the structure of the dateArray

Comment: @FrancescoD'Alesio Sorry! Just updated it now with the sturcutre of dateArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are simply looping twice.

Given it is an array, you should loop it using for, like this

```
onSelect: function(date) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
        if (date === dateArray[i].date) {
            console.log(dateArray[i].time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude that was it! I should of been using `i` instead of doing another `for...in` loop. Sorry, amateur hour over here :) thanks man!